# Технический регламент на или о?

Tags: грамотная-речь

Часто сталкиваюсь с текстами о технических регламентам (по работе) и вечно путаюсь в предлогах. Как правильно сказать (например): "технический регламент о безопасности молока и молочной продукции" или "технический регламент на безопасность молока и молочной продукции"?
Я пишу то так, то так и никак не могу определиться.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Предыдущие участники уже ответили **правильно (**или **регламентировано**) на этот вопрос, возьму лишь на себя труд объяснить почему, чтобы сомнения вас более не терзали: **регламент** – это **правила**, а правила могут быть безопасности, поведения, языка и т.д.  Не скажешь же: правила **на** поведение, правила **о** языке или **на** язык. **На** безопасность может быть **надежда,** а **о** безопасности могут быть **мечты**.

Comment: С литературной точки зрения - да, согласна. Но, когда речь идет именно о терминологии, то технические регламенты все-таки, наверное, на что-то.

Answer (score 3):

Регламент ЧЕГО? безопасности...

Answer (score 1):

"О" здесь никак не подходит.
"На" - я бы разрешил, но исключительно как дань техническому и/или канцелярскому стилю. 
А в обычном употреблении - "регламент чего", конечно.